# Difference between cuda.h, cuda_runtime.h, cuda_runtime_api.h

Tags: cuda, header-files

I'm starting to program with CUDA, and in some examples I find the include files `cuda.h`, `cuda_runtime.h` and `cuda_runtime_api.h` included in the code. Can someone explain to me the difference between these files?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

In very broad terms:

- `cuda.h` defines the public host
  functions and types for the CUDA
  **driver** API.
- `cuda_runtime_api.h` defines the public
  host    functions and types for the
  CUDA    **runtime** API
- `cuda_runtime.h` defines everything `cuda_runtime_api.h` does, as well as built-in type
  definitions and function overlays for the CUDA language extensions and
  device intrinsic functions.

If you were writing host code to be compiled with the host compiler which includes API calls, you would include either `cuda.h` or `cuda_runtime_api.h`. If you needed other CUDA language built-ins, like types, and were using the runtime API and compiling with the host compiler, you would include `cuda_runtime.h`. If you are writing code which will be compiled using nvcc, it is all irrelevant, because nvcc takes care of inclusion of all the required headers automatically without programmer intervention.

Comment: What! So you don't need to put includes in the .cu files if you compile with `nvcc` ?

Comment: Not for those particular include files, no.

Comment: Just curious (I can open a new question if needed): Just for those? Exactly those?

Comment: I haven't checked recently exactly what the import chain in recent toolkits is. But it is certainly possible to use any of the CUDA supported types and the whole of the runtime and device runtime APIs without requiring explicit import calls. If you want to use device standard library or math library functions (printf, memset, malloc, memcpy, etc), those must be specifically imported

Comment: FYI: only when the **nvcc** is compiling `.cu` code will it include all the headers automatically.

Answer (score 7):

A few observations in addition to @talonmies answer:

- `cuda_runtime.h` includes `cuda_runtime_api.h` internally, but not the other way around. So: "runtime includes all of runtime_api" is a mnemonic to remember.
- `cuda_runtime_api.h` does not have the entire runtime API functions you'll find in the official documentation, while `cuda_runtime.h` *will* have it all (example: `cudaEventCreate()`). However, all API calls defined `cuda_runtime.h` are actually implemented, in the header file itself, using calls to functions in `cuda_runtime_api.h`. These are the "function overlays" that @talonmies mentioned.
- `cuda_runtime_api.h` is a C-language header (IIANM) with only C-language function declarations; `cuda_runtime.h` is a C++ header file, with some templated functions implemented.